# Tennis Tournament

Tags: probability

Consider a tournament of 8 players, p1..p8.If the player with lower index(pi) always wins (p1 wins against everyone, P8 always loses), what is the probability that P1 and P3 meet in the final?

My Approach:

Start with 4 players:

In the 1st round, there are 3 people that P3 can be paired with. Out of this only 1 of those 3 pairings allows P3 to progress to the next round = 1/3

Thus Ans)  = 1/3 for n = 4 people

Now n = 8 people

In the 1st round, there are 7 people that P3 can be paired with of which 5 of those pairings would allow P3 to progress to the next round = 5/7

I am confused how to progress further for the next step now Would it simply be to substitute the previous case of n = 4 now thus giving us

$\frac {1} {3} $ * $\frac {5} {7} $ = $\frac {5} {21} $

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that the matches are written in a spider-type; see picture. P1 goes with P3 in finals if and only if players P1+P2 are in one half of the spider and P3 in the other half.

WLOG, say that P3 is on the right half of the spider. The probability that P1 will be on the left is (\frac{n/2}{n-1}) since there are n/2 spots on the right and n-1 spots left. Then, the probability that P2 is also on the left is 1/2, since now there are equal numbers on the right and on the left.

Together, probability is $$(\frac{n/2}{n-1})*(1/2) = \frac{1}{4}\frac{n}{n-1}. $$

[image]